# Grok filter for AWS ELB

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have the following filter in Logstash that parses AWS ELB access logs:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:loadbalancer} %{IP:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:client_port:int} (?:%{IP:backend_ip}:%{NUMBER:backend_port:int}|-) %{NUMBER:request_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:backend_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:response_processing_time:float} (?:%{NUMBER:elb_status_code:int}|-) (?:%{NUMBER:backend_status_code:int}|-) %{NUMBER:received_bytes:int} %{NUMBER:sent_bytes:int} "(?:%{WORD:verb}|-) (?:%{GREEDYDATA:request}|-) (?:HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}|-( )?)" "%{DATA:userAgent}"( %{NOTSPACE:ssl_cipher} %{NOTSPACE:ssl_protocol})?' ]
  }
}
```

which results in various fields in Elasticsearch, one being the *request* filed with a possible value of

```
https://api.example.net:443/v2/domain.com/actions?somefield=somevalue
```

Is there a way to add a second grok filter using a regex to operate on that field, before it gets indexed to ES such that *domain.com* and *v2* are extracted and indexed into their own separate fields ?

Comment: Logstash filters are serial, just build your grok filter and add it after the first one, this time use the `request` field instead of the `message` field in the match option.

Comment: two `match` statements inside one `grok` or two separate `grok` blocks, each with its own `match` ?

Comment: Two separate `grok` blocks, you can have as many as you need.

Answer (score 2):

As leandropjmp suggested, two separate grok blocks did what I wanted. Here's the complete solution I was looking for:

```
filter {

  grok {
    match => [ "message", '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:loadbalancer} %{IP:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:client_port:int} (?:%{IP:backend_ip}:%{NUMBER:backend_port:int}|-) %{NUMBER:request_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:backend_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:response_processing_time:float} (?:%{NUMBER:elb_status_code:int}|-) (?:%{NUMBER:backend_status_code:int}|-) %{NUMBER:received_bytes:int} %{NUMBER:sent_bytes:int} "(?:%{WORD:verb}|-) (?:%{GREEDYDATA:request}|-) (?:HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}|-( )?)" "%{DATA:userAgent}"( %{NOTSPACE:ssl_cipher} %{NOTSPACE:ssl_protocol})?' ]
  }
  grok {
    match => [ "request", '(/(?<request_endpoint>[^/]+)+/(?<request_version>[^/]+)+/(?<request_domain>[^/]+)/(?<request_api>[^/!\?]+))' ]
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

Just use logstash's core pattern for elb access log https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/main/patterns/ecs-v1/aws#L20

```
%{ELB_ACCESS_LOG}
```